# GridLayout won't display in a grid

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I'm using a gridLayout to simply display a 2x2 layout. I'll increase this later, but I'm just trying to get a sample to work. As of right now they line up in a single horizontal row. By just looking at my xml, does anyone see anything blatantly obvious that I'm doing wrong? My code compiles, and my xml "validates". Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.test.example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for GridLayout specifies that You should not need to use either of the special size values: WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT when configuring the children of a GridLayout. Specified in the summary [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Interesting... I removed those values, but now I get a force close.

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: I set it to 0dp, and now it doesn't force close. But it does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `GridLayout` before, but from the example [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html), it appears that you need to specify a `android:layout_column="0"` attribute when you want a new row to start. I recommend that you read the full article.

Comment: Hmm... don't think that is what `<space>` is for. They only specify one space, and that's between an editText and a button. I took my example from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaCW4uL4P6c at 2:54

Comment: "don't think that is what `<space>` is for" I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: Sorry, disregard. I thought I there was only one occurrence of `android:layout_column="0"` in `<space>`.

Comment: @EGHDK You can use `android:layout_column` for any View, including `TextView` and `EditText`.